# How to group/cluster this information about consumers?

Tags: clustering

I have several millions of rows similar to those below, describing consumers(data has been modified):

| city | road | house_number | postcode | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fort worth | sycamore school rd | 5421 | 76123 | texas |
| fort worth | sycamore school road | 4750 | 76133 | tx |

I want to group/cluster this data, so that people who live closer stay in the same group/cluster.

My idea was to join in cell by row, creating a string, e.g. for row 1 we would have "fort worth sycamore school rd 5421 76123 texas" and then use a similarity deep learning similarity model to vectorize each sentence/row, and then apply a clustering method to those vectors.

However, I found that deep learning similarity models usually use high-dimensional embeddings of 300 dim or more, and that for a clustering method seems to be highly prohibitive... Also, the similarity models that I found weren't capable of understanding that "tx" is "texas".

What would you advise me to do?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend against attempting to one-hot-encode this data, or any machine learning embedding, because your data can already be mapped to spatial coordinates using geospatial databases. Rather, I would first look at mapping these data to latitudes and longitudes.

With the latitude and longitude of each point, distances can be computed as arcs on the surface of a sphere between such points. You can use this to occupy a distance matrix.

With a distance matrix, you could perform distance-based clustering using one of a variety of algorithms. There are a lot of clustering algorithms to choose from that make tradeoffs. The Scikit-Learn package nicely visualizes this for some common algorithms.

[image]

The rows of the above grid of diagrams are some easy-to-generate data sets with varying statistical, geometric, and ([persistent](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2021.667963/full)) homological properties. The same [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) tabulates some of the aspects you might like to consider. Fortunately your (latitude, longitude) values can be readily plotted and colour-coded by the partitioning algorithm which can help you evaluate how sensible the output is.

| Method name | Parameters | Scalability | Usecase | Geometry (metric used) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K-Means | number of clusters | Very large n_samples, medium n_clusters with MiniBatch code | General-purpose, even cluster size, flat geometry, not too many clusters, inductive | Distances between points |
| Affinity propagation | damping, sample preference | Not scalable with n_samples | Many clusters, uneven cluster size, non-flat geometry, inductive | Graph distance (e.g. nearest-neighbor graph) |
| Mean-shift | bandwidth | Not scalable with n_samples | Many clusters, uneven cluster size, non-flat geometry, inductive | Distances between points |
| Spectral clustering | number of clusters | Medium n_samples, small n_clusters | Few clusters, even cluster size, non-flat geometry, transductive | Graph distance (e.g. nearest-neighbor graph) |
| Ward hierarchical clustering | number of clusters or distance threshold | Large n_samples and n_clusters | Many clusters, possibly connectivity constraints, transductive | Distances between points |
| Agglomerative clustering | number of clusters or distance threshold, linkage type, distance | Large n_samples and n_clusters | Many clusters, possibly connectivity constraints, non Euclidean distances, transductive | Any pairwise distance |
| DBSCAN | neighborhood size | Very large n_samples, medium n_clusters | Non-flat geometry, uneven cluster sizes, outlier removal, transductive | Distances between nearest points |
| OPTICS | minimum cluster membership | Very large n_samples, large n_clusters | Non-flat geometry, uneven cluster sizes, variable cluster density, outlier removal, transductive | Distances between points |
| Gaussian mixtures | many | Not scalable | Flat geometry, good for density estimation, inductive | Mahalanobis distances to centers |
| BIRCH | branching factor, threshold, optional global clusterer. | Large n_clusters and n_samples | Large dataset, outlier removal, data reduction, inductive | Euclidean distance between points |
| Bisecting K-Means | number of clusters | Very large n_samples, medium n_clusters | General-purpose, even cluster size, flat geometry, no empty clusters, inductive, hierarchical | Distances between points |

I cannot tell you *apriori* which of these algorithms will be the most suitable for your data. But hopefully this gives you a sense of some of the algorithms that are out there, and that they are non-equivalent in the partitions they recommend.

---

Here is an afterthought. The main purpose of hard clustering, as opposed to [fuzzy clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering), is to suggest a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). You can also choose partitions based on other data. For example, you could simply partition your data (spatially) by the city they live in.

---

Here is another afterthought. If you wanted to cluster by distances, you have some choice in what space you are calculating distances within. Above I recommended using arcs on a sphere. You could also use distances along paths in a transportation network (if that is relevant to your research question).

---

String mapping such as $\text{tx} \rightarrow \text{texas}$ can be done using traditional programming; no machine learning required.

Comment: Galen which algorithms would you suggest I try for distance-based clustering?